# If $m, n \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $\frac{m}{n}$ is an integer, does that imply $\frac{m}{n} \equiv 1 \pmod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

If $m, n \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $\frac{m}{n}$ is an integer, does that imply $\frac{m}{n} \equiv 1 \pmod p$?

I'm curious if this is true, I can't really think of any counterexamples. In my case, $p$ is prime, but I'm curious if this holds in general as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us write $\frac{m}{n} = k$. Then it follows that $m = kn$ and taking this equation modulo $p$ we see that
$$
1 \equiv m \equiv kn \equiv k \bmod p
$$
by our assumptions $m \equiv n \equiv 1 \bmod p$. This implies that $k \equiv 1 \bmod p$, which was to be shown.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Will accept as soon as I can